# How to set up wireshark

Tags: wireshark

wireshark will capture without stalling on my windows vista 32 bit OS, only once, if I install it, and directly after, when installation is finished, click the option to launch wireshark (as part of the GUI panel of the installer). Once I exit wireshark, and re enter the program, it will consistently stall, and crash, upon any attempt to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start here:

http://www.wireshark.org/tools/helpdesk.html

Oops - that's fake, try this:

http://ask.wireshark.org/